# calling python script from jenkinsfile prints stdout but not returning the return value

Tags: python, python-2.7, groovy, dump

I'm using the following py script and triggering it with the following groovy script. The triggering itself is done by `groovy b.jenkinsfile`:

### a.py - Python 2.7

```
import sys

def main(x):
    print x
    return 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

### b.jenkinsfile - Groovy

```
def cmd = ["python", "a.py", "arg"]
def func = cmd.execute()
func.waitForOrKill(10000)
println func.text
func.dump()
println func
```

The output I get is ["arg"] which is about what I expected (actually expected it without the [], but that's beside the point).

I can't seem to get the actual return value of the object. why is `text` / `dump` / func itself won't give the return value?

*tried also `return main(sys.argv[1:])` instead of plain calling to `main`, but that supressed my print x for some reason...*

Answer (score 1):

to get exit value use `func.exitValue()`.

the method `execute()` returns [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object instance that extended by groovy with additional [methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html)

the `[]` brackets you have because in python you are accessing the sublist of arguments starting from first one:

```
sys.argv[1:]
```

as soon as this accessor returns a list (even with only one element) - it wrapped with `[]` on output.

if you want to get just one element use

```
sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: I've been actually playing with it a little bit mnore after I posted the Q, and found the `exitValue()`, but it doesn't help without `sys.exit()` in the `.py` side, and Python can't return non-int values (I actually want to return a string)

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the value returned by the function `main()` to be passed to the OS as a return code.

It doesn't. You need to explicitly pass it to the OS.

```
rc = main(sys.argv[1:])
sys.exit(rc)
```

And you got `["arg"]` because `sys.argv[1:]` asks for a slice (that is, a sublist) of `sys.argv`. If you just want one element, use `sys.argv[1]` which selects element 1.

Comment: Please see my comment to daggett.